# How to turn a pandas dataframe row into a comma separated value with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as such:

```
id =[30,30,40,40,30,40,55,30]
month =[1,3,11,4,10,2,12,12]
average=[90,80,50,92,18,15,16,55]
sec =['id1','id1','id3','id4','id2','id2','id1','id1']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(id,sec,month,average)),columns =['id','sec','month','Average'])
```

We want to add one more column having comma separated months of below conditions

1. Need to exclude id2 sec
2. and below 90 average

Desired Output

[image]

I have tried below code but not getting desired output

```
final=pd.DataFrame()
for i in set(sec):
  if i !='id2': #Exclude id2
    d2 =df[df['sec']==i]
    d2=df[df['average']<90]  # apply below 90 condition
    d2=d2[['id','month']].groupby(['id'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(sorted(set(x.astype(str))))) #comma seperated data
    d2.rename(columns={'month':'problematic_month'},inplace=True)
    d2['sec']=i
    tab =df.merge(d2,on =['id','sec'], how ='inner')
    final =final.append(tab)
  else:
    d2 =df[df['sec']==i]
    d2['problematic_month']=np.NaN
    final =final.append(d2)
```

Kindly suggest any other way(without merge) to get the desired output

Comment: could you please add a dataframe required output?

Comment: Do you not want to use a ```merge``` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way using `groupby+transform`

```
import calendar
d = dict(enumerate(calendar.month_abbr))

s = df['month'].map(d).where(df['sec'].ne("id2")& (df['Average'].lt(90)))
col = s.groupby([df["id"],df['sec']]).transform(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()))

out = df.assign(problematic_column=col.replace("",np.nan)).sort_values(['id','sec'])
```

---

```
print(out)

   id  sec  month  Average problematic_column
0  30  id1      1       90            Mar,Dec
1  30  id1      3       80            Mar,Dec
7  30  id1     12       55            Mar,Dec
4  30  id2     10       18                NaN
5  40  id2      2       15                NaN
2  40  id3     11       50                Nov
3  40  id4      4       92                NaN
6  55  id1     12       16                Dec
```

Steps:

1. Map the month column to the calender to get month abbreviation.
2. Retain values only when the condition matches.
3. Use groupby and transform to dropna and join by comma.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by first converting your `int` months to actual Month abbreviations using `calendar`.

```
df['month'] = df['month'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])

print(df.head(3))

   id  sec month  Average
0  30  id1   Jan       90
1  30  id1   Mar       80
2  40  id3   Nov       50
```

Then I would use `loc` to narrow your dataframe based on your conditions above and a `groupby` and to get your months together per sec.

Thereafter use `map` to attach it to your initial dataframe:

```
r = df.loc[(df['Average'].gt(90) |\
           (df['sec'].eq('id2'))).eq(0)]\
    .groupby('sec').agg({'month':lambda x: ','.join(x)})\
    .reset_index()\
        .rename({'month':'problematic_month'},axis=1)

print(r)

   sec problematic_month
0  id1       Jan,Mar,Dec
1  id3               Nov

# Attach with map
df['problematic_month'] = df['sec'].map(dict(zip(r.sec,r.problematic_month)))

>>> print(df)

   id  sec month  Average problematic_month
0  30  id1   Jan       90       Jan,Mar,Dec
1  30  id1   Mar       80       Jan,Mar,Dec
2  40  id3   Nov       50               Nov
3  40  id4   Apr       92               NaN
4  30  id2   Oct       18               NaN
5  40  id2   Feb       15               NaN
6  55  id1   Dec       16       Jan,Mar,Dec
```

Then using this problematic_month column, you can check whether it contains a `,` and it it does you can select the first and last column:

```
import numpy as np
f = df['problematic_month'].str.split(',').str[0] 
l = ',' +  df['problematic_month'].str.split(',').str[-1]

df['problematic_month'] = np.where(df['problematic_month'].str.contains(','),f+l, df['problematic_month'])
```

Answer:

```
>>> print(df)

   id  sec month  Average problematic_month
0  30  id1   Jan       90           Jan,Dec
1  30  id1   Mar       80           Jan,Dec
2  40  id3   Nov       50               Nov
3  40  id4   Apr       92               NaN
4  30  id2   Oct       18               NaN
5  40  id2   Feb       15               NaN
6  55  id1   Dec       16           Jan,Dec
```